# MYSQL insert data from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have 2 tables and I need to add the value **"user"** from the table **user** to the table **Album** where user is.

**Table1 (user)**

```
Id_user  auto_increase 
user   
Password
```

**Table2 (album)**

```
IdAlbum auto_increase
Title
Descripcion
user  text
```

Comment: Have you Google'd `"how to add data from one table into another mysql"` ? That first result should solve it.

Comment: Do you really need that? I would create a relationship between those tables instead.

Comment: Note: you might want to normalize your data - save the user ID into table2 instead of username.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `Table2` 
    SELECT (NULL,"some title","some description",`user`) 
    FROM `Table1` WHERE `Id_user`="12345";`
```

This will select the username for user 12345 from Table1 and insert it into Table2.